# Ionic slides are laggy, how to improve?

Tags: ionic-framework

So, I built an Ionic application, using the sidemenu bar, some  and made a few CRUDs.

I'm very newbie in Ionic, but I noticed a laggy transition when I slide, when I click, sometimes I have to click twice on a button to get a response.

I'm using lazy loading already, but what else can I do in order to improve my sliding experiences?

Comment: What are you testing/developing on where it feels laggy? I know with some animations (mainly around the drawer) I get some lag using an Android emulator, but then it is smooth on device.

Comment: Feels laggy when I slide to the right an <ion-item-sliding> or when I scroll down, and sometimes when I click on a button. i'm testing on the device, and a good one